# angular2 Share data between pages with multi instances

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm writing an Ionic app using angular2 - Lets take the MasterDetail pattern for example:

`MasterPage` is a components that displays a list.

`DetailPage` is a component that displays a single item from the list.

`ListService` is a service holding the data of a single list to be shared for both `MasterPage` and `DetailPage` so all changes applied to a single item such as edit will update the `MasterPage` as well.

**But** what if I have **multi instances** of the `MasterPage` - lets say I have a `MenuPage` with menu-items which I can open a list from.

So my navigation could be something like this:

`MenuPage` -> `MasterPage` -> `DetailPage` -> `MenuPage` (from a menu button on the header) -> second `MasterPage` displaying a different list.

How can I have **multiple instances of the `ListService`** where each set of `MasterPage` - `DeatilPage` shares a single instance?

Comment: I don't get what the problem with 1 is. If you have a shared service and update the service state from the detail page, then the master page will see these changes as well.

Comment: yes, But how can this service hold the data for multiple instances (with different lists) at once?

Comment: Just provide the service on the `MasterPage` and each `MasterPage` `DetailPage` pair will have their own service instance.

Comment: I didn't know that - you could write it as an answer - I will edit the question to fit your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a service in `@NgModule(...)` of `AppModule` you get a single instance for your whole application.

If you provide a service in `@Component(...)` then each component instance will get its own service instance and share it with its children.

Providers on a component override providers on `AppModule` and providers on parent components, for the component itself and their child components.

There is always a single instance per provider. If a provider is added to a component, there will be as many instances of this provider as there are instances of the component.

Comment: But how do I make the `DetailPage` a child component of the specific `MasterPage` (so it gets the right instance of the service) as they are all pages in the nav stack?

Comment: Are you using the router? Then you need to place the `<router-outlet>` inside the `MasterPage`.

Comment: I'm using the ionic `NavController` I don't think there is an option to do this. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: Sorry, don't know Ionic. But for example `@ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController` and ` this.nav.push(Page1);` looks like `Page1` is made a child of the current component.